# How to direct mail by From: address?

Tags: email, postfix

I have postfix running and directing mail to a smarthost at my ISP.  I would like email with a particular outgoing email address to be forwarded to another server, specifically GMail; all the rest through the ISP.  e.g. Outgoing mail labelled From: X@gmail.com should be sent via the X account on GMail, rather than through the ISP.  This is fairly straightforward on end-user mail clients, so hopefully I just missed the obvious for postfix.  Only one such address need be supported for this.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775648/postfix-does-not-sender-based-routing-with-postmap

Comment: note that sender-based routing is based on the envelope sender address, which may or may not be the same as the From: header in the message.  As far as mail routing is concerned, headers are irrelevant - only the envelope matters.

Comment: The other question gives me a lead.   Not sure what the envelope From header is when it leaves mutt, this might be something set by Postfix.

Comment: by default, mutt uses the From: header as the envelope sender, but there are ways to override that.  and mutt isn't the only thing that can send mail on a system.  The point of my comment was that i was highlighting the difference between headers and envelope, which IME is one thing about mail that many people either don't know about or have difficulty understanding.